# Using D3.js, How can I detect when a point on an animating line is reached?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3 I want to detect when my animating line changes direction (or reaches a point) , and append a circle at the very point in time.  So that one circle will append at a time as opposed to the all of them, which is what is currently happening.

```
var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var path = svg.append("path")
    .data([points])
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) ); //); // Catmull–Rom 
    //.interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(10000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);


svg.selectAll(".point", function(d,i){
        console.log(d,i)
    })
    .data(points)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .style("fill", "url(#image)")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hs5a9z5a/2/)

I tried measuring the last x and y verse the previous x and y, but if they both continue to move in the positive direction or negative direction it won't be easy noticing a difference.   I would also need to measure the slope change.  I'm hoping there is a smarter way?

I tried measuring to see if the difference between newX and oldX remained the same, but it's not working :( https://jsfiddle.net/hs5a9z5a/3/

Comment: If you want to check for direction change, the check if the new `x` or `y` value is less/greater than the old value.

Comment: I tried that.  If u look at the second fiddle.  It's not just greater or less, since that'll be different for a straight line.  It's the difference of X2 - X1, but still i don't think I'm implementing it correctly

Comment: You want to know when the line hits a data point?

Comment: @Mark Yes that's really all I wanted

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes I'll type up an answer...

Comment: @Mark Awesome Thanks  https://jsfiddle.net/hs5a9z5a/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell when the line changes directions (ie hits your data points), you need to take control of the transition function on your `stroke-dashoffset`.  This is how I'd do it (I'd tried to comment it well, let me know if you have any questions):

```
path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease("linear")
  .tween("myTween", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolate(totalLength, 0);
    var self = d3.select(this);
    return function(t) {
        // current position of stroke-dashoffset     
        var len = i(t),
        // current position with respect to line length of stroke-dashoffset
        per = (1 - len / totalLength) * totalLength,
        // pixel position of stroke-dashoffset
        p = self.node().getPointAtLength(per);

      // loop our points and look for hit detection
      points.forEach(function(d) {
        // are we one a point?
        if (Math.abs(p.x - d[0]) < 1 && Math.abs(p.y - d[1]) < 1) {
          console.log("point hit");
        }
      });

      // apply stroke-dashoffset
      self.attr("stroke-dashoffset", len);
    };
  });
```

Running sample:

```js
var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500);


var path = svg.append("path")
  .data([points])
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0)); //); // Catmull–Rom 
//.interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease("linear")
  .tween("myTween", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolate(totalLength, 0);
    var self = d3.select(this);
    return function(t) {
      var len = i(t),
        per = (1 - len / totalLength) * totalLength,
        p = self.node().getPointAtLength(per);

      points.forEach(function(d) {
        if (Math.abs(p.x - d[0]) < 1 && Math.abs(p.y - d[1]) < 1) {
          console.log("point hit");
        }
      });
      
      self.attr("stroke-dashoffset", i(t));
    };
  });




/*
svg.selectAll(".point", function(d,i){
  //console.log(d,i)
 })
 .data(points)
 .enter().append("circle")
 .transition()
 .duration(2000)
 .ease("linear")
 .style("fill", "url(#image)")
 .attr("r", 20)
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })
    
var circle = svg.append("circle")
 .attr("r", 13)
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + points[0] + ")");

transition();

function transition() {
 circle.transition()
 .duration(10000)
 .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
 //.each("end", transition);
 .each("end");
}

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
*/
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

circle {
  fill: url('http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg');
  fill: steelblue;
  /stroke: #fff;
  //stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<svg id="mySvg" width="80" height="80">
  <defs id="mdef">
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg"></image>

    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: @Squirrl, yes, the `1` in `Math.abs(p.x - d[0]) < 1` is essentially your hit threshold.  The higher the speed, the less precision you'll get between animation steps and you can "step-over" the point.  If you choose a value > 1 you can hone this in based on your speed.

Comment: Another option -- now that you know how to control the transition, is to apply @MaximilianPeters slope change algorithm there.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the code below which is based on your fiddle.

`slope` is an array which is a vector for x and y.
It's calculated by subtracting `p.x` and the last x coordinate and dividing it by the time difference. If it is higher than the `threshold`, a message is written to the console.

```js
var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);


var path = svg.append("path")
 .data([points])
 .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
 .tension(0) ); //); // Catmull–Rom 

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
 .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
 .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
 .transition()
 .duration(10000)
 .ease("linear")
 .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

svg.selectAll(".point", function(d,i){})
 .data(points)
 .enter().append("circle")
 .transition()
 .duration(2000)
 .ease("linear")
 .style("fill", "url(#image)")
 .attr("r", 20)
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })
    
var circle = svg.append("circle")
 .attr("r", 13)
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + points[0] + ")");

transition();

function transition() {
 circle.transition()
 .duration(10000)
 .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
 .each("end");
}

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
var newX = 0, diffX = 0, prevdiffX=0, oldX=0; 
var newY = 0;
var newT = 0;
function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    var slope = [];
    slope.push('-1');
    slope.push('-1');
    var threshold = 0.1;



    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {

            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      
            if ((1 - Math.abs(slope[0]/((p.x - newX)  / (t - newT) + 0.001))) > 0.1) {
                console.log('slopeX changed');
            } else if ((1 - Math.abs(slope[1]/((p.y - newY)  / (t - newT) + 0.001))) > 0.1) {
                console.log('slopeY changed');
            }
            slope = [];
            slope.push((p.x - newX)  / (t - newT) + 0.001);
            slope.push((p.y - newY) / (t - newT) + 0.001);
   newX = p.x; 
            newY = p.y;
            newT = t;
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
            };
        };
    }
```

```css
path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}

circle {
 fill: url('http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg');

 fill: steelblue;
  /stroke: #fff;
  //stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg" width="80" height="80">
  <defs id="mdef">
  <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg"></image>

  </pattern>
  </defs> 
 </svg>
  <div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thank you.  Is there anyway to tie it to the line as oppose to the circle?